# Hibernate questions

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I started learning hibernate and I want to clarify some questions that cannot be cleared by simple googling. The questions are concerning interaction of deleteOrphan, cascade types and different association mapping types. Let me begin. Sincere thanks in advance.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_member", schema = "church")
public class Member implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "t_event_members", joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
                }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
                })
    private Set<Event> events;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_event", schema = "church")
public class Event implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "events", 
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<Member> members;
}
```

1. The member is the owning side. During the active session I retrieve
   a    member. If I remove an event from members collection and
   perform    saveOrUpdate will the corresponding member be removed
   from the event?
2. How does the "owning side" affects cascading in this case?
3. What happens when we mix orphanDelete with CascadeType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Simply removing an event from the Member will have no effect in this case since you have not mapped orphan delete.  The act of removing event from Member leaves that event an orphan, which is the basis of the term 'orphan delete'.  And since you "retrieved the member during an active session", that member is "managed"; no need to call saveOrUpdate.  The state of managed objects are tracked by Hibernate.

2) Most cascade types are valid on either side of an association (orphan-delete is the exception to this).  Cascading says to cascade the operation just performed on the one thing to another.  Owning or not describes which side Hibernate will use to drive the state of that association in the database.  For illustration of this last point, here you have bi-directional many-to-many.  Rows in the 't_event_members' table are represented twice in memory: once as element in Member.events and again as element in Event.members.  Owning essentially defines which side to trust in cases where those 2 might be different.

3) orphan delete actually is cascade type to Hibernate.  JPA defines it separately from cascade types (as annotation attribute) so we obviously support that as well.

BTW orphan delete and many-to-many are not compatible.

Comment: Great answer, Steve!
I have one more question. CascadeType.REMOVE and orphan delete stand for different things? In the 1st case associated entities are removed from the DB and in the 2nd case the associated entities remove assosiations to the entity being removed, right?

Comment: You say orphan delete is not compatible with ManyToMany so is there a comfortable way I can manage references in the associated entities?

Comment: Well let me clarify.  There is a difference here.  In (1) I was maybe not perfectly clear; there the Event will not be deleted.  That is the purpose of orphan delete.  Cleaning up rows from 't_event_members' will happen based on the state of Member.events.  So when you remove an Event from Member.events that corresponding row will be removed from 't_event_members'.  That has nothing to do with orphan delete.  Orphan delete says to actually delete the Event in that same case.  That cannot happen in a many-to-many.

Comment: And if I remove an event from Event.members will the corresponding row be removed from t_event_members?

Comment: No, in fact you just defined owning versus non-owning.